# Itext7 page settings and margin using C#

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am working on an application where I need to restrict my HTML to a single pdf page. How can I change settings to my pdf using Itext7? Below is my HTML

```
string htmlContent = $@"<!DOCTYPE html>
                                        <html lang=""en"">
                                        <head>
                                            <meta charset=""UTF-8"">
                                            <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"">
                                        </head>
                                        <body>
                                            <div style=""position: relative;"">
                                                <div style=""padding: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px;"">
                                                    <img height=""80px"" width=""220px"" src=""{image1Url}"" alt="""" srcset="""">
                                                    <p style=""margin-top: -40pt;padding-left: 188pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"">
                                                        <span style="" color: #007E00; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14pt;"">1</span>
                                                        <span style="" color: #007E00; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt; vertical-align: 4pt;"">ère</span>
                                                        <span style="" color: #007E00; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14pt;"">solution
                                                            de paiement par mobile à Madagascar</span>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div style=""border-bottom: 20px solid #ffde00; margin-top: -5px;""></div>
                                                <div style=""padding: 20px;"">
                                                    <div style=""margin-bottom: 20px;"">
                                                        <h3>ATTESTATION DE TRANSFERT VIA MVOLA
                                                        </h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div style=""margin-bottom: 50px;"">
                                                        <p style=""margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                            {dto.Name}</p>
                                                        <p style=""margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                            Mobile : {dto.Msisdn}</p>
                                                        <p style=""margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                            E-mail : {dto.Email}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div style=""border-top: 3px solid #ffde00; border-bottom: 3px solid #ffde00; padding: 20px 0px; margin-bottom: 50px;"">
                                                        <table style=""width: 100%;"">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th style=""text-align: start;"">Libellé</th>
                                                                    <th style=""text-align: start;"">Date</th>
                                                                    <th style=""text-align: start;"">Référence</th>
                                                                    <th style=""text-align: start;"">Montant</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style=""text-align: start;"">{dto.Description}</td>
                                                                    <td style=""text-align: start;"">{dto.TransDate}</td>
                                                                    <td style=""text-align: start;"">{dto.TransID}</td>
                                                                    <td style=""text-align: start;"">{dto.Amount} Ar</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div style=""padding: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px;"">
                                                        <p style=""margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                            À conserver pour vos archives</p>
                                                        <h3 style=""margin-bottom: 40px;"">TOUJOURS PLUS SIMPLE AVEC MVOLA!</h3>
                                                         <div style=""style=""height: 700px;"""">
                                                            <img src=""{image2Url}"" alt="""" height=""auto"" width=""100%"" style=""max-height: 600px;"">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div style=""margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 20px; background-color: #ffde00;"">
                                                    <table style=""width: 100%;"">
                                                        <tbody>

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style=""width: 50%; text-align: start;"">
                                                                    <div style=""margin-bottom: 10px; color: #007E00;"">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="" margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                                            Service Client MVola : 807</p>
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style=""margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                                            E-mail : <a href=""mailto:mvola@telma.mg"">mvola@telma.mg</a></p>
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style=""margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"">
                                                                            <a href=""http://www.mvola.mg/MVola_mobile_money.php""> www.mvola.mg</a>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style=""width: 50%; text-align: end;"">
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <img src=""{image3Url}"" alt="""" srcset="""" height=""80px"" width=""220px"">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </body>
                                        </html>";
```

Below is my C# code

```
public string GeneratePdfFromHtmlAndConvertToBase64(string htmlContent)
        {
            try
            {
                string base64String;
                _logger.LogInformation($"Request ID: {_localSessionManager.InternalTransectionSessionID} - GeneratePdfFromHtmlAndConvertToBase64, Request: {htmlContent}");

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var writerProperties = new WriterProperties();

                    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream, writerProperties))
                    {
                        using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                        {
                            var doc = new Document(pdfDocument);
                            doc.SetMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                            
                            pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlContent, pdfDocument, new ConverterProperties());
                        }
                    }

                    var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                }

                _logger.LogInformation($"Request ID: {_localSessionManager.InternalTransectionSessionID} - GeneratePdfFromHtmlAndConvertToBase64, base64String: {base64String}");

                return base64String;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Request ID: {_localSessionManager.InternalTransectionSessionID} - GeneratePdfFromHtmlAndConvertToBase64, Exception Occurred: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I need to add the below settings

```
DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" 
PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10, Bottom = 10 },
```

Comment: Could you providea PDF document how it currently looks? It will be easier to help you out.

Comment: it rendering in 2 pages